# how to reset symfony admin password?

Tags: authentication, symfony1, passwords

I am hosting symfony project , the login password for backend.php was lost.

from phpmyadmin I see there is salted password. What data I should use to let me login?

I tried `123` with SHA1 for salt field, `123abcd` for password field with SHA1, and tried to login with `abcd` password with no luck.

any help ?

Comment: Which plugin are you using for user authentication? sfDoctrineGuard?

Comment: I do not know and I am not the programmer and I do not have any idea about this framework , I just provide the hosting for it .

Comment: Without the specifics it's very hard to give a definitive answer though, so maybe you should find out the details first.

Comment: If it's sfGuardPlugin in Symfony 1.x, [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090975/symfony-sfguardplugin-password-recovery/5093066#5093066) might help, especially the `guard:change-password` action.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about sfDoctrineGuard? If so, you can find the code for hashing a password here: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php#L42

In the database you should see the algorithm used for hashing. By default this would be 
sha1, but this doesn't need to be the case. If it is sha1, the passwordfield should indeed be the value of `sha1($salt.$password)`. To be clear, for a salt of '123' and the password 'abcd' the value in the database should be '50360551b49f1181e06c8244402634838c1e1a99'.

Note that there can be other things preventing you from logging in too, like a user set to inactive (see the 'is_active' field).

Comment: Thank you so much, but I do not understand !!

the user table is : sf_guard_user
algorithm : sha1
is_active:1
for salt 123 I typed : 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef
for password 123abcd I typed : 50360551b49f1181e06c8244402634838c1e1a99

that not worked for me